# Linked SharePoint List not producing correct data in REST query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, office365apis

I am trying to use the Office 365 SharePoint REST API to pull data stored in a list on SharePoint.

There are 2 columns in the list that lookup to another list.

I am trying to query the list using:

```
.../site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Sample Lists')/items?$select=Email/Title&$expand=Email
```

The Email column in the list stores a lookup to a user table that then stores the Email. However, when I run the expand in this manner, I am not given a list of the Emails and am instead given a list of names (the other lookup value in the original list).

Comment: What is the data type of your Email column in another list from which you have added lookup to your list? Can you please add screenshot or something of columns in Provider/Parent list used in lookup.

Comment: @GaneshSanap where can I find the data type in Sharepoint/find the columns in Provider parent lookup?

Comment: Go to the parent list(in your case, User table). open the list settings scroll down to **Columns** section. take a screenshot of it and add it to your question.

Comment: What is the name of the column that stores the email in the user table list?

Comment: @DylanCristy The name of the column that stores the email in the user table is 'Work email'

Answer (score 0):

The way expanding lookup columns works is that you specify the name of the lookup column in the main list you are querying, and then specify the name of the column you want data from in the lookup list.

So in your example, the name of the lookup column in the list you are querying is `Email`, but the name of the column that stores the email in the lookup list is `Work email`.  So what you really want to `$select` is `$select=Email/WorkEmail`.  When you do `$select=Email/Title` you are saying "give me data from the `Title` field in the lookup list", which I'm guessing stores the users' names, since that's what you said is the data you're getting.

Also, keep in mind, you need to be specifying the *internal* name of the column in the lookup list.  In the comments above you said the name of the column is `Work email`, but I doubt very highly that that's what the internal name is.  To find the internal name of the `Work email` column in the user table list, go to the user table list, go to the list settings, scroll down to the "Columns" section, and click on the name of the `Work email` column as if you are going to edit the column settings.  When you get to the "Edit Column" page, look in the browser's address bar and look for the query parameter `&Field=SomeName`.  That `SomeName` will be the internal name of the column, and that's what you should use in your `$select`.